# Delimiting equations in math mode

Tags: delimiters

I'm trying to delimit an equation with parentheses and it has fractions inside it, so I can't just increase the parentheses' size, because they wouldn't be correctly alligned. What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
MDC(m,n)=mindiv(m,n)$\times$ MDC $\left($ $\dfrac{m}{mindiv(m,n)}$,$\dfrac{n}{mindiv(m,n)}$ $\right)$
```

It compiles correctly until I attempt to add the parentheses like that. I've tried all possible ways to add the math mode delimiters, but all it does is give me a series of errors. How do I delimit bigger equations like this in math mode? I found out that the following works:

```
$\left( \right)$
```

However, if I attempt to wrap the equation like that (with the delimiters at the beginning and at the end only), I still get a series of errors.

Comment: ...then you haven't "tried all possible ways"...

Comment: Yeah, indeed I hadn't. I have just had an insight which actually worked.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why are you *jumping* out of mathmode continously?

Comment: Thank you! I had initially thought I needed to delimit math mode whenever I wanted to add a math *symbol*, only now I found out I would jump in and out of math mode doing that. A single pair of delimiters wrapping the entire piece of code is enough, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong...

You should switch to math-mode and stay there in order to set math content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mindiv}{mindiv}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MDC}{MDC}
\begin{document}
\[
  \MDC(m,n) = \mindiv(m,n) \times \MDC \biggl( \dfrac{m}{\mindiv(m,n)}, \dfrac{n}{\mindiv(m,n)} \biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

I've declared some operators since it seemed to suit your needs. Also, you can use `\left(...\right)`, but I've decided (for spacing consistency) to use `\big`-like delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Jumping out of mathmode using $...$ is not a pretty good way. Use a common $...$ pair or `\[...\]` or a math environment as `equation` or `align`.

The function names should be wrapped into a `\DeclareMathOperator` statement to provide upright typesetting and better spacing, however, admitted, I had done this only for `\mindiv` so far. I leave it to the OP as an exercise for the `\MDC` operator ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mindiv}{mindiv}

\begin{document}


$MDC(m,n)=\mindiv(m,n) \times MDC \left(\dfrac{m}{\mindiv(m,n)},\dfrac{n}{\mindiv(m,n)}\right)$

\begin{align}
MDC(m,n) &=\mindiv(m,n) \times MDC \left(\dfrac{m}{\mindiv(m,n)},\dfrac{n}{\mindiv(m,n)}\right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `MDC` is wrong: if you want italics it should be `\mathit{MDC}`.

Comment: @egreg: See the 'explanation' in the post ;-)